# What is the order of execution when a module is installed?

Tags: 8

I have a question and I don't know how the execution order is established when a module is installed.

If I install a custom module, which one is installed first?

a)

1.- The `config/install` folder

2.- Hook install

b)

1.- Hook install

2.- The `config/install` folder